# Asserting a value is exactly equal to undefined

Tags: javascript, tdd, undefined, assert, qunit

When using `qunit` to test, asserting that a value is specifically, exactly undefined is difficult. I am looking for a function that will:

1. compare against `undefined` so that a value of `undefined` satisfies the assertion, but anything else (including `null`) will fail the test
2. provide useful feedback on a failure akin to "expected undefined; got 'foobar'"

Note: using `strictEqual`, `propEqual`, or `deepEqual` will handle the first criteria. However, those assertion functions yield no useful information in the failure message unless specifically added as the optional argument in the assertion.

As an alternative to direct comparisons, any time I need to make this assertion, my indirect approach is `equal(typeof exampleValue, 'undefined')`.

Is there anything available in `qunit` to handle this?

Comment: Why not just write your own function that does an `===` comparison?

Comment: That might be an option. I was hoping for something standard to qunit.

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript:

```
(typeof(someVariable) === "undefined")
```

In QUnit:

```
strictEqual(typeof(someVariable), "undefined")
```

http://api.qunitjs.com/strictEqual/